# How to match a script using preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

The original text

```
window.DATA_STORE = {
        isMobile: false,
        data: {"visitsList":{"data":[{"userId":"NkEQmWDdKzwyXKbGMJZj","userName":"GeroChile","userGender":1,"userAge":36,"userCity":"","userPicId":"axe63o2ak7xhqa6ng86ucxoaxgf75na29bqgw9ol","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/a\/x\/axe63o2ak7xhqa6ng86ucxoaxgf75na29bqgw9ol_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/a\/x\/axe63o2ak7xhqa6ng86ucxoaxgf75na29bqgw9ol_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=NkEQmWDdKzwyXKbGMJZj&c=513cf8852f2a335b5a6b0dbd21c7df5fcf6c543c","userLastVisited":"heute, 02:30 Uhr"},{"userId":"rjLvKgNbDmznPrdmYGWo","userName":"Zuckerstange1","userGender":1,"userAge":56,"userCity":"","userPicId":"5g8cpfsxrlq1689cebzasodzehcyed4wx81ja21z","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/5\/g\/5g8cpfsxrlq1689cebzasodzehcyed4wx81ja21z_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/5\/g\/5g8cpfsxrlq1689cebzasodzehcyed4wx81ja21z_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=rjLvKgNbDmznPrdmYGWo&c=8011959c2842141f6dfb066ee4cfbf46aba59196","userLastVisited":"gestern, 01:44 Uhr"},{"userId":"knjlBZmawrnmMWeMxLpW","userName":"Tom_0990","userGender":1,"userAge":29,"userCity":"","userPicId":"gbjo38nz31a9ahjn11hozj5mh7tzd1tq27re71yc","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/g\/b\/gbjo38nz31a9ahjn11hozj5mh7tzd1tq27re71yc_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/g\/b\/gbjo38nz31a9ahjn11hozj5mh7tzd1tq27re71yc_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=knjlBZmawrnmMWeMxLpW&c=10dd411df2eeeeffb793d9472b842c98c4928ee1","userLastVisited":"gestern, 00:55 Uhr"},{"userId":"qlBWrvxbzBBYkmbKZjPJ","userName":"Lieblingsjunge","userGender":1,"userAge":49,"userCity":"","userPicId":"lsxkyko6ay412dt057zziy3u62umswgxm2e6xwp8","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/l\/s\/lsxkyko6ay412dt057zziy3u62umswgxm2e6xwp8_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/l\/s\/lsxkyko6ay412dt057zziy3u62umswgxm2e6xwp8_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=qlBWrvxbzBBYkmbKZjPJ&c=89da3babf04a621b8474ece8585073b38d1c0c54","userLastVisited":"gestern, 00:24 Uhr"},{"userId":"VWKqlByarzzmRxaNLYjZ","userName":"Triskell","userGender":1,"userAge":48,"userCity":"","userPicId":"co5fzvna3ph464bd1mit9c344pmjf1fxaqf35spz","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/c\/o\/co5fzvna3ph464bd1mit9c344pmjf1fxaqf35spz_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/c\/o\/co5fzvna3ph464bd1mit9c344pmjf1fxaqf35spz_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=VWKqlByarzzmRxaNLYjZ&c=d25c234771e97ba2c348089e09bc1abf6018d693","userLastVisited":"gestern, 19:13 Uhr"}],"count":5,"settings":{"m":1,"g":0,"v":2}},"onlineList":{"data":[{"userId":"wRGYvAQdklgEYJemzENj","userName":"Chaosmak3r","userGender":1,"userAge":24,"userCity":"Chemnitz","userPicId":"ua6mjj8qrrgqwwm9yn64914alfwhv7925oavqjb0","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/u\/a\/ua6mjj8qrrgqwwm9yn64914alfwhv7925oavqjb0_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/u\/a\/ua6mjj8qrrgqwwm9yn64914alfwhv7925oavqjb0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=wRGYvAQdklgEYJemzENj&c=aeb85869ec7398deb60c7e2cc11b5fbc35ff3133","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"AJDqGPgbQJJXJYdpRWvj","userName":"Sv_Pro","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Freiberg","userPicId":"nbv7opbdtsmtia1phx2zije1plss6fhdkgt34tks","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/n\/b\/nbv7opbdtsmtia1phx2zije1plss6fhdkgt34tks_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/n\/b\/nbv7opbdtsmtia1phx2zije1plss6fhdkgt34tks_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=AJDqGPgbQJJXJYdpRWvj&c=8fabf3ad40118c62f6e5a7b1c78fd0b4bf875941","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"mZEWKkpbjjNgRPbQRLrD","userName":"Jonas13","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"W\u00fcrzburg","userPicId":"l6w56bjht51xfb82t1v1p8f55o1m81n5auyu7f6e","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/l\/6\/l6w56bjht51xfb82t1v1p8f55o1m81n5auyu7f6e_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/l\/6\/l6w56bjht51xfb82t1v1p8f55o1m81n5auyu7f6e_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=mZEWKkpbjjNgRPbQRLrD&c=80185000c609e075542f2e5275657aae87ee812d","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"kvgNmRKdGgLjgodLJjlX","userName":"Schrauber-93","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Meerane","userPicId":"kgqueqjcjylct9eovlxgcu1ieyuxmpmovujdpa5j","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/k\/g\/kgqueqjcjylct9eovlxgcu1ieyuxmpmovujdpa5j_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/k\/g\/kgqueqjcjylct9eovlxgcu1ieyuxmpmovujdpa5j_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=kvgNmRKdGgLjgodLJjlX&c=60b0bea55b4bdf6b4d33f3134c51a53ec98d3d6b","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"YMwlJyRaMroxGPbPLpkW","userName":"Martin993","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Darmstadt","userPicId":"no5aorjkha2h2oo5btwit4ffky1vdao86eehh9b0","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/n\/o\/no5aorjkha2h2oo5btwit4ffky1vdao86eehh9b0_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/n\/o\/no5aorjkha2h2oo5btwit4ffky1vdao86eehh9b0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=YMwlJyRaMroxGPbPLpkW&c=2c5cf6795f85cbc2a6f2b8181fae4aaa427431f0","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"lvrEojzayvvlyPbPnWBX","userName":"Thommy06","userGender":1,"userAge":21,"userCity":"Chemnitz","userPicId":"3hzs7fw2rnnj86tlanonsd6wmnzj833qxg7o0cqm","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/3\/h\/3hzs7fw2rnnj86tlanonsd6wmnzj833qxg7o0cqm_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/3\/h\/3hzs7fw2rnnj86tlanonsd6wmnzj833qxg7o0cqm_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=lvrEojzayvvlyPbPnWBX&c=84b645c5e04ecc0661aa12c3b1c232ab38c86bec","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"rmxkNywanlpNEgdAXjpM","userName":"Furkan","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Heppenheim","userPicId":"a4p6qizw6pc8t2x4der3tbh60i7whal3zvfq3hr0","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/a\/4\/a4p6qizw6pc8t2x4der3tbh60i7whal3zvfq3hr0_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/a\/4\/a4p6qizw6pc8t2x4der3tbh60i7whal3zvfq3hr0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=rmxkNywanlpNEgdAXjpM&c=d1e85439cf80704a95d6cbf2eeccc399392f5204","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"GpgXMNmbxnBQqKeJzqRw","userName":"Keksian","userGender":1,"userAge":24,"userCity":"Leipzig","userPicId":"5uh9dhfe39272oo6ub1wwskfvfvt5jjprqh5aihl","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/5\/u\/5uh9dhfe39272oo6ub1wwskfvfvt5jjprqh5aihl_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/5\/u\/5uh9dhfe39272oo6ub1wwskfvfvt5jjprqh5aihl_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=GpgXMNmbxnBQqKeJzqRw&c=500212e2e649fef4ed13a4d80b601664afdea77e","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NqDMnwpapqqmAYbyJQPZ","userName":"Felixmagicetea","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Schwalmstadt","userPicId":"sgps7lk67shsdfgjndqzb8hdgrqlavb06pp74742","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/s\/g\/sgps7lk67shsdfgjndqzb8hdgrqlavb06pp74742_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/s\/g\/sgps7lk67shsdfgjndqzb8hdgrqlavb06pp74742_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=NqDMnwpapqqmAYbyJQPZ&c=212f0a9ab1193108e6a8809b3e84577c9e1c903e","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NpEQvGqaWBBWXkewPBAj","userName":"Flint93","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Helmstedt","userPicId":"vmq19yu3kw24u11g4flqzihw6jnlc5m5npndyptx","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/v\/m\/vmq19yu3kw24u11g4flqzihw6jnlc5m5npndyptx_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/v\/m\/vmq19yu3kw24u11g4flqzihw6jnlc5m5npndyptx_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=NpEQvGqaWBBWXkewPBAj&c=97afffd0a631005cd82465ad20b692e82839e63e","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"GpgXMNmaxrrJqwdJzqRw","userName":"FitteFimmel","userGender":1,"userAge":22,"userCity":"Erlensee","userPicId":"8wttu8sd6iqmyxocfsgr3a8kg8i0cv0tq6f0qty0","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/8\/w\/8wttu8sd6iqmyxocfsgr3a8kg8i0cv0tq6f0qty0_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/8\/w\/8wttu8sd6iqmyxocfsgr3a8kg8i0cv0tq6f0qty0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=GpgXMNmaxrrJqwdJzqRw&c=76d7567c4dc34451240bee64bedaeb3b8a991305","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NqDMnwpepjXyyybyJQPZ","userName":"Matatta","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Kirchberg","userPicId":"adv23qwo4rcbosnpwd4wb2bt7kfzksw7v47d10zq","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/a\/d\/adv23qwo4rcbosnpwd4wb2bt7kfzksw7v47d10zq_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/a\/d\/adv23qwo4rcbosnpwd4wb2bt7kfzksw7v47d10zq_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=NqDMnwpepjXyyybyJQPZ&c=1371068df70bcd7bfac071fc9d0584a11e72069e","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"rjLvKgNbDmmvEPdmYGWo","userName":"LautundDrau\u00dfen","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Erfurt","userPicId":"5y0d0vzxanjjjgwsprbahdp4i9zxwt9f4tvaxfh0","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/5\/y\/5y0d0vzxanjjjgwsprbahdp4i9zxwt9f4tvaxfh0_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/5\/y\/5y0d0vzxanjjjgwsprbahdp4i9zxwt9f4tvaxfh0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=rjLvKgNbDmmvEPdmYGWo&c=ab801a62580085f365128d564f75b56e9a3fcc62","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"xENlwKBeJwzMZKaWkLGy","userName":"michi27z","userGender":1,"userAge":21,"userCity":"Gro\u00df-Zimmern","userPicId":"jmoiu2oa2io99x805sr78b7of261wnj7y60o2r7e","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/j\/m\/jmoiu2oa2io99x805sr78b7of261wnj7y60o2r7e_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/j\/m\/jmoiu2oa2io99x805sr78b7of261wnj7y60o2r7e_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=xENlwKBeJwzMZKaWkLGy&c=8b66ca15c6df77a031b087457c363cf011667403","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"xENlwKBaJlDVpJdWkLGy","userName":"roger007","userGender":1,"userAge":21,"userCity":"G\u00f6ttingen","userPicId":"1k64izt75xajcx6ghd8mar4on7skzd0xjmp2jzef","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/1\/k\/1k64izt75xajcx6ghd8mar4on7skzd0xjmp2jzef_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/1\/k\/1k64izt75xajcx6ghd8mar4on7skzd0xjmp2jzef_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=xENlwKBaJlDVpJdWkLGy&c=d9f0b63b9f46d6439bceb99715c49f85592ba8fb","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"qlBWrvxdzBBAnMdKZjPJ","userName":"Samy20","userGender":1,"userAge":20,"userCity":"Regensburg","userPicId":"fb85lk1osol8cgvga3o7hrfaosa0fbkskpgtmtv2","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/f\/b\/fb85lk1osol8cgvga3o7hrfaosa0fbkskpgtmtv2_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/f\/b\/fb85lk1osol8cgvga3o7hrfaosa0fbkskpgtmtv2_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=qlBWrvxdzBBAnMdKZjPJ&c=e7c6ea2e85059413bdcda620e57282cebfdcf84a","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"QwrXmEvePrWZnZbPNKYl","userName":"themanno","userGender":1,"userAge":24,"userCity":"Marbach","userPicId":"vj57hx7h6yb47zjarlb1xqnx6grqbd8u7lz8dpo7","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/v\/j\/vj57hx7h6yb47zjarlb1xqnx6grqbd8u7lz8dpo7_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/v\/j\/vj57hx7h6yb47zjarlb1xqnx6grqbd8u7lz8dpo7_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=QwrXmEvePrWZnZbPNKYl&c=36baed1660b0738c8e1d94866761ebb9ba9c1795","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"rmxkNywenlLpmrbAXjpM","userName":"SlimFelix","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Butzbach","userPicId":"a94xbhq7t6z403n8tjuptn2rekjzrspluotdh5jk","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/a\/9\/a94xbhq7t6z403n8tjuptn2rekjzrspluotdh5jk_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/a\/9\/a94xbhq7t6z403n8tjuptn2rekjzrspluotdh5jk_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=rmxkNywenlLpmrbAXjpM&c=3ec55bd03374bc48410360726626cf2d31d61dbe","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"xENlwKBeJPkNMAbWkLGy","userName":"Magicdrinkmix","userGender":1,"userAge":23,"userCity":"N\u00fcrnberg","userPicId":"yc8wzs7c0nrnt8e0mq7ai97vjfszyj93obvj4or0","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/y\/c\/yc8wzs7c0nrnt8e0mq7ai97vjfszyj93obvj4or0_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/y\/c\/yc8wzs7c0nrnt8e0mq7ai97vjfszyj93obvj4or0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=xENlwKBeJPkNMAbWkLGy&c=11154131780def40accd9d70a92d789436fec79d","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NkEQmWDbKpLQpNdGMJZj","userName":"Thommy96","userGender":1,"userAge":23,"userCity":"Gotha","userPicId":"7xcgqzna0tp8h3tdk5y95dopad9m85ybmcpckmou","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/7\/x\/7xcgqzna0tp8h3tdk5y95dopad9m85ybmcpckmou_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/7\/x\/7xcgqzna0tp8h3tdk5y95dopad9m85ybmcpckmou_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=NkEQmWDbKpLQpNdGMJZj&c=84861a1ac988775acf71e35c5771cb3ae91664ff","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NpEQvGqaWMRBMldwPBAj","userName":"wabb93","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Eltville","userPicId":"7a9n68fm0reo7pwz0yjg4alvas5zxtq2ex5gffe0","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/7\/a\/7a9n68fm0reo7pwz0yjg4alvas5zxtq2ex5gffe0_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/7\/a\/7a9n68fm0reo7pwz0yjg4alvas5zxtq2ex5gffe0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=NpEQvGqaWMRBMldwPBAj&c=4dc1d4de6d84ca82e1e0f7db9ae5956b6ea24b56","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"VMvxkKXaYJPDywbGrZNA","userName":"ag01","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Bad Rappenau","userPicId":"jpyn10kvo65yzu79yo3bzc97ne2vt5p82xj747ke","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/j\/p\/jpyn10kvo65yzu79yo3bzc97ne2vt5p82xj747ke_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/j\/p\/jpyn10kvo65yzu79yo3bzc97ne2vt5p82xj747ke_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=VMvxkKXaYJPDywbGrZNA&c=7face200cafb74d3258ddc7534fec9924c65a423","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"lvrEojzaynkpkwbPnWBX","userName":"Ullyses","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Heidelberg","userPicId":"bhugirynumzsshdo810qqtc73kkro7yvaiwna062","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/b\/h\/bhugirynumzsshdo810qqtc73kkro7yvaiwna062_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/b\/h\/bhugirynumzsshdo810qqtc73kkro7yvaiwna062_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=lvrEojzaynkpkwbPnWBX&c=7a35caca31aa4649f7be04e445564eaff40287ff","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"mZEWKkpejjQnYqeQRLrD","userName":"Tjoram","userGender":1,"userAge":23,"userCity":"Breitenstein","userPicId":"nd9nh79utpmh72ftvmjg7alyb1nyb7zayczefn36","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/n\/d\/nd9nh79utpmh72ftvmjg7alyb1nyb7zayczefn36_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/n\/d\/nd9nh79utpmh72ftvmjg7alyb1nyb7zayczefn36_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=mZEWKkpejjQnYqeQRLrD&c=8cd13591aa66512c9a1e3cb9878130027be2593c","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"ZVlQXBpeXMmkwwagnzYy","userName":"David1998","userGender":1,"userAge":20,"userCity":"Nordhausen","userPicId":"o12mquwzsb90g38vhqlrihtz0vwqjvt8ds79y5yj","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/o\/1\/o12mquwzsb90g38vhqlrihtz0vwqjvt8ds79y5yj_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/o\/1\/o12mquwzsb90g38vhqlrihtz0vwqjvt8ds79y5yj_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=ZVlQXBpeXMmkwwagnzYy&c=88dff6b62ee053584614d555a19dfeade9e305f1","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"ZVlQXBpaXMMqkVbgnzYy","userName":"Tong888","userGender":1,"userAge":27,"userCity":"Wendeburg","userPicId":"ld5u2if97c3w7sfbztjqhkpgvs5donba8mbfmmsb","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/l\/d\/ld5u2if97c3w7sfbztjqhkpgvs5donba8mbfmmsb_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/l\/d\/ld5u2if97c3w7sfbztjqhkpgvs5donba8mbfmmsb_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=ZVlQXBpaXMMqkVbgnzYy&c=a949f31628241f4fddef9f7da7609fc15067bb70","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"GpgXMNmaxrrKzEdJzqRw","userName":"RWa99","userGender":1,"userAge":19,"userCity":"Bad Nauheim","userPicId":"h5yfkebxej1ccbszb5zwki2ve6m7frm4v83428ip","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/h\/5\/h5yfkebxej1ccbszb5zwki2ve6m7frm4v83428ip_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/h\/5\/h5yfkebxej1ccbszb5zwki2ve6m7frm4v83428ip_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=GpgXMNmaxrrKzEdJzqRw&c=c7f302870f6139d66c4de0997ac49bad4a7c1708","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"qoyVNXZdLRnpnRaPgYWv","userName":"malte99","userGender":1,"userAge":19,"userCity":"Gie\u00dfen","userPicId":"lmwoo5l3qd5do09suyvsd06ab37qk1qjepoddcy0","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/l\/m\/lmwoo5l3qd5do09suyvsd06ab37qk1qjepoddcy0_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/l\/m\/lmwoo5l3qd5do09suyvsd06ab37qk1qjepoddcy0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=qoyVNXZdLRnpnRaPgYWv&c=cae66604fa7aa6ea514e70d87a215dc43d764ca0","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NqDMnwpbpqqmDgdyJQPZ","userName":"MarcSchneider","userGender":1,"userAge":27,"userCity":"Wetzlar","userPicId":"bnpp58irqzwinl2k76oppjesmsp2mpfy72valgne","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/b\/n\/bnpp58irqzwinl2k76oppjesmsp2mpfy72valgne_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/b\/n\/bnpp58irqzwinl2k76oppjesmsp2mpfy72valgne_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":false,"userIsOnline":true,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=NqDMnwpbpqqmDgdyJQPZ&c=2edb9524fa70168fe93ae247c3833b80e0e7fda4","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"VWKqlByerzgqqjeNLYjZ","userName":"Erzwo93","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Weiterstadt","userPicId":"47kg45gyoqfs65gklaevshc2dmeieuaa7fclqt34","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/4\/7\/47kg45gyoqfs65gklaevshc2dmeieuaa7fclqt34_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/4\/7\/47kg45gyoqfs65gklaevshc2dmeieuaa7fclqt34_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=VWKqlByerzgqqjeNLYjZ&c=88acd872c5561d9c91427b4fbfc49bb7ff551e10","userLastVisited":""}],"count":199,"ts":"1559181753","settings":{"v":2}},"user":{"hasFavoritesOnline":false,"hasNewMessages":true,"hasNewNotifications":false,"hasNewHearts":false,"hasNewFeed":true,"hasProfilePic":false,"nickname":"sabhbau14","id_pic":"","gender":2,"id":"ogmJyDPalmEqPmbYEVRr","lastlogin":1559167342},"userSettings":{"bubbles":{"feed-visitors":0,"feed-visited":0,"feed-favorites":0,"info-gallery":0,"info-matching":0,"info-search":0,"info-mobile-likes":0,"info-mobile-search-custom":0,"info-mobile-search-newbies":0,"info-mobile-search-online":0,"info-mobile-favorites":0,"info-heart-sent":0,"deprecate-ie":1}},"context":"default","page":1,"pages_total":1,"userlist":[{"userId":"","userName":"vybz-kartel28","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Duisburg","userPicId":"wp24e3tn8m1rqlor90f3ithrwaqzsnoxv5zp6abj","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/w\/p\/wp24e3tn8m1rqlor90f3ithrwaqzsnoxv5zp6abj_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/w\/p\/wp24e3tn8m1rqlor90f3ithrwaqzsnoxv5zp6abj_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":false,"userIsOnline":true,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=knjlBZmdwrLzvVbMxLpW&c=48e7012db31d2944b912f83ff24af9dbee8fd7c3","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"","userName":"Hanni89","userGender":1,"userAge":29,"userCity":"Laatzen","userPicId":"xiyx3e1bck1u033278wsp53xonxvhf5l9jy7n56q","userPictures":{"small":"\/content\/u\/x\/i\/xiyx3e1bck1u033278wsp53xonxvhf5l9jy7n56q_12.jpg","medium":"\/content\/u\/x\/i\/xiyx3e1bck1u033278wsp53xonxvhf5l9jy7n56q_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":false,"userIsOnline":true,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\/User\/profile\/?id=rmxkNywbnvvNVAbAXjpM&c=554a87e863f1b8f65a95a91575fed925e775dcca","userLastVisited":""},],"params":{"a1":"18","a2":"30","ct":"100006207","di":"200","g":"1","nm":"1","o":"1","pc":"1","ct_meta":{"id":"100006207","country":"de","city":"Paderborn","state":"Nordrhein-Westfalen","state_short":"NW","locality":"","id_zip_center":"7071","id_city_proxy":"100006207"}},"results_total":9,"max_per_page":30,"position":1,"getvars":{"ct":"100006207","g":"1","a1":"18","a2":"30","di":"200","ec":"","rx":"","sh":"","v1":"","hs":"","hc":"","h1":"","h2":"","ch":"","cp":"","ed":"","sm":"","zo":"","se":"","mo":"","o":"1","nm":"1","im":"","nn":""},"base_url":"\/Search","nopage_url":"\/Search\/?ct=100006207&g=1&a1=18&a2=30&di=200&ec=&rx=&sh=&v1=&hs=&hc=&h1=&h2=&ch=&cp=&ed=&sm=&zo=&se=&mo=&o=1&nm=1&im=&nn=&","msg":"few_results","countries":{"de":"Deutschland","at":"\u00d6sterreich","ch":"Schweiz","eg":"\u00c4gypten","gq":"\u00c4quartorialguinea","et":"\u00c4thiopien","af":"Afghanistan","al":"Albanien","dz":"Algerien","ad":"Andorra","ao":"Angola","ag":"Antigua und Barbuda","ar":"Argentinien","am":"Armenien","az":"Aserbeidschan","au":"Australien","bs":"Bahamas","bh":"Bahrein","bd":"Bangladesch","bb":"Barbados","by":"Belarus","be":"Belgien","bz":"Belize","bj":"Benin","bt":"Bhutan","bo":"Bolivien","ba":"Bosnien und Herzegowina","bw":"Botsuana","br":"Brasilien","bn":"Brunei","bg":"Bulgarien","bf":"Burkina Faso","bi":"Burundi","cl":"Chile","cn":"China","cr":"Costa Rica","ci":"Cote d'Ivoire","dk":"D\u00e4nemark","dm":"Dominica","do":"Dominikanische Republik","dj":"Dschibuti","ec":"Ecuador","sv":"El Salvador","er":"Eritrea","ee":"Estland","fo":"Far\u00f6er","fj":"Fidschi","fi":"Finnland","fr":"Frankreich","ga":"Gabun","gm":"Gambia","ge":"Georgien","gh":"Ghana","gi":"Gibraltar","gd":"Grenada","gr":"Griechenland","gb":"Gro\u00dfbritannien","gt":"Guatemala","gn":"Guinea","gw":"Guinea-Bissau","gy":"Guyana","ht":"Haiti","hn":"Honduras","hk":"Hongkong","in":"Indien","id":"Indonesien","iq":"Irak","ir":"Iran","ie":"Irland","is":"Island","il":"Israel","it":"Italien","jm":"Jamaika","jp":"Japan","ye":"Jemen","jo":"Jordanien","kh":"Kambodscha","cm":"Kamerun","ca":"Kanada","cv":"Kap Verde","kz":"Kasachstan","qa":"Katar","ke":"Kenia","kg":"Kirgisistan","ki":"Kiribati","co":"Kolumbien","km":"Komoren","cg":"Kongo (Republik)","cd":"Kongo Dem. Republik","kp":"Korea (Nord) Dem. Volksrep.","kr":"Korea (S\u00fcd) Republik","hr":"Kroatien","cu":"Kuba","kw":"Kuwait","la":"Laotische Dem. Volksrep.","ls":"Lesotho","lv":"Lettland","lb":"Libanon","lr":"Liberia","ly":"Libysch-Arabische Republik","li":"Liechtenstein","lt":"Litauen","lu":"Luxemburg","mo":"Macao","mg":"Madagaskar","mw":"Malawi","my":"Malaysia","mv":"Malediven","ml":"Mali","mt":"Malta","ma":"Marokko","mh":"Marshallinseln","mr":"Mauretanien","mu":"Mauritius","mk":"Mazedonien","mx":"Mexiko","fm":"Mikronesien","md":"Moldau","mc":"Monaco","mn":"Mongolei","me":"Montenegro","mz":"Mosambik","mm":"Myanmar","na":"Namibia","nr":"Nauru","np":"Nepal","nz":"Neuseeland","ni":"Nicaragua","nl":"Niederlande","ne":"Niger","ng":"Nigeria","nu":"Niue","mp":"N\u00f6rdliche Marianen","no":"Norwegen","om":"Oman","pk":"Pakistan","pw":"Palau","ps":"Pal\u00e4stina","pa":"Panama","pg":"Papua-Neuguinea","py":"Paraguay","pe":"Peru","ph":"Philippinen","pl":"Polen","pt":"Portugal","rw":"Ruanda","ro":"Rum\u00e4nien","ru":"Russische F\u00f6deration","sb":"Salomonen","zm":"Sambia","ws":"Samoa","sm":"San Marino","st":"Sao Tome und Principe","sa":"Saudi Arabien","se":"Schweden","sn":"Senegal","rs":"Serbien","sc":"Seychellen","sl":"Sierra Leone","zw":"Simbabwe","sg":"Singapur","sk":"Slowakische Republik","si":"Slowenien","so":"Somalia","es":"Spanien","lk":"Sri Lanka","kn":"St. Kitts und Nevis","lc":"St. Lucia","vc":"St. Vincent","sd":"Sudan","za":"S\u00fcdafrika","sr":"Suriname","sz":"Swasiland","sy":"Syrien","tj":"Tadschikistan","tw":"Taiwan","tz":"Tansania","tl":"Timor-Leste","th":"Thailand","tg":"Togo","to":"Tonga","tt":"Trinidad und Tobago","td":"Tschad","cz":"Tschechische Republik","tr":"T\u00fcrkei","tn":"Tunesien","tm":"Turkmenistan","tv":"Tuvalu","ug":"Uganda","ua":"Ukraine","hu":"Ungarn","uy":"Uruguay","us":"USA","uz":"Usbekistan","vu":"Vanuatu","va":"Vatikanstadt","ve":"Venezuela","ae":"Vereinigte Arab. Emirate","vn":"Vietnam","cf":"Zentralafrik. Republik"},"requestUri":"\/Search?ct=100006207&g=1&a1=18&a2=30&di=200&ec=&rx=&sh=&v1=&hs=&hc=&h1=&h2=&ch=&cp=&ed=&sm=&zo=&se=&mo=&o=1&nm=1&im=&nn=","bubble_search":"\n<div class=\"tooltip tt-scheme1 tt-size2\" id=\"bubbleExpireNotice\" style=\"margin: 10px 0 20px;\">\n    <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"tt-close\" data-closeaction=\"\/Ajax\/hideBubble\" data-closedata=\"info-search\" title=\"Diesen Hinweis nicht mehr anzeigen\"><\/a>\n    <div class=\"tt-title tt-title-info\">Sie suchen \u2013 wir finden f\u00fcr Sie<\/div>\n    <p>\n        Wie stellen Sie sich Ihren Traumpartner vor? Wie alt, wie jung, wie gro\u00df? Nutzen Sie die umfangreichen\n        M\u00f6glichkeiten der Partnersuche, und lassen Sie sich \u00fcberraschen.\n    <\/p>\n<\/div>\n"},

      };

(function() { var run = function()
```

How can I get string between `window.DATA_STORE =` and `(function() { var run = function()`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using `preg_match`, with the following regex pattern:

```
window\.DATA_STORE.*?(?=\(function\(\) \{)
```

Sample script:

```
$input = "window.DATA_STORE = {
    isMobile: false,
    data: {\"visitsList\":{\"data\":[{\"userId\":\"NkEQmWDdKzwyXKbGMJZj\",\"userName\":\"GeroChile\"}

  };

  (function() { var run = function()";

preg_match('/window\.DATA_STORE.*?(?=\(function\(\) \{)/s', $input, $matches); 
print_r($matches);
```

Note carefully that the regex is run in DOT ALL mode, with `/s` modifier in the call to `preg_match`.  Here is an explanation of the regex:

```
window\.DATA_STORE     match literal "window.DATA_STORE"
.*?                    followed by any content (across lines) until
(?=\(function\(\) \{)  looking ahead and seeing "(function() {"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, we would use a `[\s\S]*` which collects all chars including new lines in our expression:

```
 /(window\.DATA_STORE[\s\S]*var run = function\(\))/m
```

#### Test

```
$re = '/(window\.DATA_STORE[\s\S]*var run = function\(\))/m';
$str = 'window.DATA_STORE = {
        isMobile: false,
        data: {"visitsList":{"data":[{"userId":"NkEQmWDdKzwyXKbGMJZj","userName":"GeroChile","userGender":1,"userAge":36,"userCity":"","userPicId":"axe63o2ak7xhqa6ng86ucxoaxgf75na29bqgw9ol","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/a\\/x\\/axe63o2ak7xhqa6ng86ucxoaxgf75na29bqgw9ol_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/a\\/x\\/axe63o2ak7xhqa6ng86ucxoaxgf75na29bqgw9ol_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=NkEQmWDdKzwyXKbGMJZj&c=513cf8852f2a335b5a6b0dbd21c7df5fcf6c543c","userLastVisited":"heute, 02:30 Uhr"},{"userId":"rjLvKgNbDmznPrdmYGWo","userName":"Zuckerstange1","userGender":1,"userAge":56,"userCity":"","userPicId":"5g8cpfsxrlq1689cebzasodzehcyed4wx81ja21z","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/5\\/g\\/5g8cpfsxrlq1689cebzasodzehcyed4wx81ja21z_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/5\\/g\\/5g8cpfsxrlq1689cebzasodzehcyed4wx81ja21z_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=rjLvKgNbDmznPrdmYGWo&c=8011959c2842141f6dfb066ee4cfbf46aba59196","userLastVisited":"gestern, 01:44 Uhr"},{"userId":"knjlBZmawrnmMWeMxLpW","userName":"Tom_0990","userGender":1,"userAge":29,"userCity":"","userPicId":"gbjo38nz31a9ahjn11hozj5mh7tzd1tq27re71yc","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/g\\/b\\/gbjo38nz31a9ahjn11hozj5mh7tzd1tq27re71yc_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/g\\/b\\/gbjo38nz31a9ahjn11hozj5mh7tzd1tq27re71yc_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=knjlBZmawrnmMWeMxLpW&c=10dd411df2eeeeffb793d9472b842c98c4928ee1","userLastVisited":"gestern, 00:55 Uhr"},{"userId":"qlBWrvxbzBBYkmbKZjPJ","userName":"Lieblingsjunge","userGender":1,"userAge":49,"userCity":"","userPicId":"lsxkyko6ay412dt057zziy3u62umswgxm2e6xwp8","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/l\\/s\\/lsxkyko6ay412dt057zziy3u62umswgxm2e6xwp8_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/l\\/s\\/lsxkyko6ay412dt057zziy3u62umswgxm2e6xwp8_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=qlBWrvxbzBBYkmbKZjPJ&c=89da3babf04a621b8474ece8585073b38d1c0c54","userLastVisited":"gestern, 00:24 Uhr"},{"userId":"VWKqlByarzzmRxaNLYjZ","userName":"Triskell","userGender":1,"userAge":48,"userCity":"","userPicId":"co5fzvna3ph464bd1mit9c344pmjf1fxaqf35spz","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/c\\/o\\/co5fzvna3ph464bd1mit9c344pmjf1fxaqf35spz_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/c\\/o\\/co5fzvna3ph464bd1mit9c344pmjf1fxaqf35spz_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=VWKqlByarzzmRxaNLYjZ&c=d25c234771e97ba2c348089e09bc1abf6018d693","userLastVisited":"gestern, 19:13 Uhr"}],"count":5,"settings":{"m":1,"g":0,"v":2}},"onlineList":{"data":[{"userId":"wRGYvAQdklgEYJemzENj","userName":"Chaosmak3r","userGender":1,"userAge":24,"userCity":"Chemnitz","userPicId":"ua6mjj8qrrgqwwm9yn64914alfwhv7925oavqjb0","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/u\\/a\\/ua6mjj8qrrgqwwm9yn64914alfwhv7925oavqjb0_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/u\\/a\\/ua6mjj8qrrgqwwm9yn64914alfwhv7925oavqjb0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=wRGYvAQdklgEYJemzENj&c=aeb85869ec7398deb60c7e2cc11b5fbc35ff3133","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"AJDqGPgbQJJXJYdpRWvj","userName":"Sv_Pro","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Freiberg","userPicId":"nbv7opbdtsmtia1phx2zije1plss6fhdkgt34tks","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/n\\/b\\/nbv7opbdtsmtia1phx2zije1plss6fhdkgt34tks_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/n\\/b\\/nbv7opbdtsmtia1phx2zije1plss6fhdkgt34tks_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=AJDqGPgbQJJXJYdpRWvj&c=8fabf3ad40118c62f6e5a7b1c78fd0b4bf875941","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"mZEWKkpbjjNgRPbQRLrD","userName":"Jonas13","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"W\\u00fcrzburg","userPicId":"l6w56bjht51xfb82t1v1p8f55o1m81n5auyu7f6e","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/l\\/6\\/l6w56bjht51xfb82t1v1p8f55o1m81n5auyu7f6e_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/l\\/6\\/l6w56bjht51xfb82t1v1p8f55o1m81n5auyu7f6e_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=mZEWKkpbjjNgRPbQRLrD&c=80185000c609e075542f2e5275657aae87ee812d","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"kvgNmRKdGgLjgodLJjlX","userName":"Schrauber-93","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Meerane","userPicId":"kgqueqjcjylct9eovlxgcu1ieyuxmpmovujdpa5j","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/k\\/g\\/kgqueqjcjylct9eovlxgcu1ieyuxmpmovujdpa5j_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/k\\/g\\/kgqueqjcjylct9eovlxgcu1ieyuxmpmovujdpa5j_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=kvgNmRKdGgLjgodLJjlX&c=60b0bea55b4bdf6b4d33f3134c51a53ec98d3d6b","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"YMwlJyRaMroxGPbPLpkW","userName":"Martin993","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Darmstadt","userPicId":"no5aorjkha2h2oo5btwit4ffky1vdao86eehh9b0","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/n\\/o\\/no5aorjkha2h2oo5btwit4ffky1vdao86eehh9b0_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/n\\/o\\/no5aorjkha2h2oo5btwit4ffky1vdao86eehh9b0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=YMwlJyRaMroxGPbPLpkW&c=2c5cf6795f85cbc2a6f2b8181fae4aaa427431f0","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"lvrEojzayvvlyPbPnWBX","userName":"Thommy06","userGender":1,"userAge":21,"userCity":"Chemnitz","userPicId":"3hzs7fw2rnnj86tlanonsd6wmnzj833qxg7o0cqm","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/3\\/h\\/3hzs7fw2rnnj86tlanonsd6wmnzj833qxg7o0cqm_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/3\\/h\\/3hzs7fw2rnnj86tlanonsd6wmnzj833qxg7o0cqm_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=lvrEojzayvvlyPbPnWBX&c=84b645c5e04ecc0661aa12c3b1c232ab38c86bec","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"rmxkNywanlpNEgdAXjpM","userName":"Furkan","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Heppenheim","userPicId":"a4p6qizw6pc8t2x4der3tbh60i7whal3zvfq3hr0","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/a\\/4\\/a4p6qizw6pc8t2x4der3tbh60i7whal3zvfq3hr0_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/a\\/4\\/a4p6qizw6pc8t2x4der3tbh60i7whal3zvfq3hr0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=rmxkNywanlpNEgdAXjpM&c=d1e85439cf80704a95d6cbf2eeccc399392f5204","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"GpgXMNmbxnBQqKeJzqRw","userName":"Keksian","userGender":1,"userAge":24,"userCity":"Leipzig","userPicId":"5uh9dhfe39272oo6ub1wwskfvfvt5jjprqh5aihl","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/5\\/u\\/5uh9dhfe39272oo6ub1wwskfvfvt5jjprqh5aihl_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/5\\/u\\/5uh9dhfe39272oo6ub1wwskfvfvt5jjprqh5aihl_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=GpgXMNmbxnBQqKeJzqRw&c=500212e2e649fef4ed13a4d80b601664afdea77e","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NqDMnwpapqqmAYbyJQPZ","userName":"Felixmagicetea","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Schwalmstadt","userPicId":"sgps7lk67shsdfgjndqzb8hdgrqlavb06pp74742","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/s\\/g\\/sgps7lk67shsdfgjndqzb8hdgrqlavb06pp74742_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/s\\/g\\/sgps7lk67shsdfgjndqzb8hdgrqlavb06pp74742_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=NqDMnwpapqqmAYbyJQPZ&c=212f0a9ab1193108e6a8809b3e84577c9e1c903e","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NpEQvGqaWBBWXkewPBAj","userName":"Flint93","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Helmstedt","userPicId":"vmq19yu3kw24u11g4flqzihw6jnlc5m5npndyptx","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/v\\/m\\/vmq19yu3kw24u11g4flqzihw6jnlc5m5npndyptx_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/v\\/m\\/vmq19yu3kw24u11g4flqzihw6jnlc5m5npndyptx_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=NpEQvGqaWBBWXkewPBAj&c=97afffd0a631005cd82465ad20b692e82839e63e","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"GpgXMNmaxrrJqwdJzqRw","userName":"FitteFimmel","userGender":1,"userAge":22,"userCity":"Erlensee","userPicId":"8wttu8sd6iqmyxocfsgr3a8kg8i0cv0tq6f0qty0","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/8\\/w\\/8wttu8sd6iqmyxocfsgr3a8kg8i0cv0tq6f0qty0_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/8\\/w\\/8wttu8sd6iqmyxocfsgr3a8kg8i0cv0tq6f0qty0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=GpgXMNmaxrrJqwdJzqRw&c=76d7567c4dc34451240bee64bedaeb3b8a991305","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NqDMnwpepjXyyybyJQPZ","userName":"Matatta","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Kirchberg","userPicId":"adv23qwo4rcbosnpwd4wb2bt7kfzksw7v47d10zq","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/a\\/d\\/adv23qwo4rcbosnpwd4wb2bt7kfzksw7v47d10zq_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/a\\/d\\/adv23qwo4rcbosnpwd4wb2bt7kfzksw7v47d10zq_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=NqDMnwpepjXyyybyJQPZ&c=1371068df70bcd7bfac071fc9d0584a11e72069e","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"rjLvKgNbDmmvEPdmYGWo","userName":"LautundDrau\\u00dfen","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Erfurt","userPicId":"5y0d0vzxanjjjgwsprbahdp4i9zxwt9f4tvaxfh0","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/5\\/y\\/5y0d0vzxanjjjgwsprbahdp4i9zxwt9f4tvaxfh0_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/5\\/y\\/5y0d0vzxanjjjgwsprbahdp4i9zxwt9f4tvaxfh0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=rjLvKgNbDmmvEPdmYGWo&c=ab801a62580085f365128d564f75b56e9a3fcc62","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"xENlwKBeJwzMZKaWkLGy","userName":"michi27z","userGender":1,"userAge":21,"userCity":"Gro\\u00df-Zimmern","userPicId":"jmoiu2oa2io99x805sr78b7of261wnj7y60o2r7e","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/j\\/m\\/jmoiu2oa2io99x805sr78b7of261wnj7y60o2r7e_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/j\\/m\\/jmoiu2oa2io99x805sr78b7of261wnj7y60o2r7e_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=xENlwKBeJwzMZKaWkLGy&c=8b66ca15c6df77a031b087457c363cf011667403","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"xENlwKBaJlDVpJdWkLGy","userName":"roger007","userGender":1,"userAge":21,"userCity":"G\\u00f6ttingen","userPicId":"1k64izt75xajcx6ghd8mar4on7skzd0xjmp2jzef","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/1\\/k\\/1k64izt75xajcx6ghd8mar4on7skzd0xjmp2jzef_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/1\\/k\\/1k64izt75xajcx6ghd8mar4on7skzd0xjmp2jzef_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=xENlwKBaJlDVpJdWkLGy&c=d9f0b63b9f46d6439bceb99715c49f85592ba8fb","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"qlBWrvxdzBBAnMdKZjPJ","userName":"Samy20","userGender":1,"userAge":20,"userCity":"Regensburg","userPicId":"fb85lk1osol8cgvga3o7hrfaosa0fbkskpgtmtv2","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/f\\/b\\/fb85lk1osol8cgvga3o7hrfaosa0fbkskpgtmtv2_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/f\\/b\\/fb85lk1osol8cgvga3o7hrfaosa0fbkskpgtmtv2_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=qlBWrvxdzBBAnMdKZjPJ&c=e7c6ea2e85059413bdcda620e57282cebfdcf84a","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"QwrXmEvePrWZnZbPNKYl","userName":"themanno","userGender":1,"userAge":24,"userCity":"Marbach","userPicId":"vj57hx7h6yb47zjarlb1xqnx6grqbd8u7lz8dpo7","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/v\\/j\\/vj57hx7h6yb47zjarlb1xqnx6grqbd8u7lz8dpo7_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/v\\/j\\/vj57hx7h6yb47zjarlb1xqnx6grqbd8u7lz8dpo7_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=QwrXmEvePrWZnZbPNKYl&c=36baed1660b0738c8e1d94866761ebb9ba9c1795","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"rmxkNywenlLpmrbAXjpM","userName":"SlimFelix","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Butzbach","userPicId":"a94xbhq7t6z403n8tjuptn2rekjzrspluotdh5jk","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/a\\/9\\/a94xbhq7t6z403n8tjuptn2rekjzrspluotdh5jk_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/a\\/9\\/a94xbhq7t6z403n8tjuptn2rekjzrspluotdh5jk_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=rmxkNywenlLpmrbAXjpM&c=3ec55bd03374bc48410360726626cf2d31d61dbe","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"xENlwKBeJPkNMAbWkLGy","userName":"Magicdrinkmix","userGender":1,"userAge":23,"userCity":"N\\u00fcrnberg","userPicId":"yc8wzs7c0nrnt8e0mq7ai97vjfszyj93obvj4or0","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/y\\/c\\/yc8wzs7c0nrnt8e0mq7ai97vjfszyj93obvj4or0_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/y\\/c\\/yc8wzs7c0nrnt8e0mq7ai97vjfszyj93obvj4or0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=xENlwKBeJPkNMAbWkLGy&c=11154131780def40accd9d70a92d789436fec79d","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NkEQmWDbKpLQpNdGMJZj","userName":"Thommy96","userGender":1,"userAge":23,"userCity":"Gotha","userPicId":"7xcgqzna0tp8h3tdk5y95dopad9m85ybmcpckmou","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/7\\/x\\/7xcgqzna0tp8h3tdk5y95dopad9m85ybmcpckmou_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/7\\/x\\/7xcgqzna0tp8h3tdk5y95dopad9m85ybmcpckmou_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=NkEQmWDbKpLQpNdGMJZj&c=84861a1ac988775acf71e35c5771cb3ae91664ff","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NpEQvGqaWMRBMldwPBAj","userName":"wabb93","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Eltville","userPicId":"7a9n68fm0reo7pwz0yjg4alvas5zxtq2ex5gffe0","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/7\\/a\\/7a9n68fm0reo7pwz0yjg4alvas5zxtq2ex5gffe0_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/7\\/a\\/7a9n68fm0reo7pwz0yjg4alvas5zxtq2ex5gffe0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=NpEQvGqaWMRBMldwPBAj&c=4dc1d4de6d84ca82e1e0f7db9ae5956b6ea24b56","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"VMvxkKXaYJPDywbGrZNA","userName":"ag01","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Bad Rappenau","userPicId":"jpyn10kvo65yzu79yo3bzc97ne2vt5p82xj747ke","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/j\\/p\\/jpyn10kvo65yzu79yo3bzc97ne2vt5p82xj747ke_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/j\\/p\\/jpyn10kvo65yzu79yo3bzc97ne2vt5p82xj747ke_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=VMvxkKXaYJPDywbGrZNA&c=7face200cafb74d3258ddc7534fec9924c65a423","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"lvrEojzaynkpkwbPnWBX","userName":"Ullyses","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Heidelberg","userPicId":"bhugirynumzsshdo810qqtc73kkro7yvaiwna062","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/b\\/h\\/bhugirynumzsshdo810qqtc73kkro7yvaiwna062_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/b\\/h\\/bhugirynumzsshdo810qqtc73kkro7yvaiwna062_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=lvrEojzaynkpkwbPnWBX&c=7a35caca31aa4649f7be04e445564eaff40287ff","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"mZEWKkpejjQnYqeQRLrD","userName":"Tjoram","userGender":1,"userAge":23,"userCity":"Breitenstein","userPicId":"nd9nh79utpmh72ftvmjg7alyb1nyb7zayczefn36","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/n\\/d\\/nd9nh79utpmh72ftvmjg7alyb1nyb7zayczefn36_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/n\\/d\\/nd9nh79utpmh72ftvmjg7alyb1nyb7zayczefn36_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=mZEWKkpejjQnYqeQRLrD&c=8cd13591aa66512c9a1e3cb9878130027be2593c","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"ZVlQXBpeXMmkwwagnzYy","userName":"David1998","userGender":1,"userAge":20,"userCity":"Nordhausen","userPicId":"o12mquwzsb90g38vhqlrihtz0vwqjvt8ds79y5yj","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/o\\/1\\/o12mquwzsb90g38vhqlrihtz0vwqjvt8ds79y5yj_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/o\\/1\\/o12mquwzsb90g38vhqlrihtz0vwqjvt8ds79y5yj_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=ZVlQXBpeXMmkwwagnzYy&c=88dff6b62ee053584614d555a19dfeade9e305f1","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"ZVlQXBpaXMMqkVbgnzYy","userName":"Tong888","userGender":1,"userAge":27,"userCity":"Wendeburg","userPicId":"ld5u2if97c3w7sfbztjqhkpgvs5donba8mbfmmsb","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/l\\/d\\/ld5u2if97c3w7sfbztjqhkpgvs5donba8mbfmmsb_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/l\\/d\\/ld5u2if97c3w7sfbztjqhkpgvs5donba8mbfmmsb_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=ZVlQXBpaXMMqkVbgnzYy&c=a949f31628241f4fddef9f7da7609fc15067bb70","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"GpgXMNmaxrrKzEdJzqRw","userName":"RWa99","userGender":1,"userAge":19,"userCity":"Bad Nauheim","userPicId":"h5yfkebxej1ccbszb5zwki2ve6m7frm4v83428ip","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/h\\/5\\/h5yfkebxej1ccbszb5zwki2ve6m7frm4v83428ip_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/h\\/5\\/h5yfkebxej1ccbszb5zwki2ve6m7frm4v83428ip_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=GpgXMNmaxrrKzEdJzqRw&c=c7f302870f6139d66c4de0997ac49bad4a7c1708","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"qoyVNXZdLRnpnRaPgYWv","userName":"malte99","userGender":1,"userAge":19,"userCity":"Gie\\u00dfen","userPicId":"lmwoo5l3qd5do09suyvsd06ab37qk1qjepoddcy0","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/l\\/m\\/lmwoo5l3qd5do09suyvsd06ab37qk1qjepoddcy0_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/l\\/m\\/lmwoo5l3qd5do09suyvsd06ab37qk1qjepoddcy0_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":false,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=qoyVNXZdLRnpnRaPgYWv&c=cae66604fa7aa6ea514e70d87a215dc43d764ca0","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"NqDMnwpbpqqmDgdyJQPZ","userName":"MarcSchneider","userGender":1,"userAge":27,"userCity":"Wetzlar","userPicId":"bnpp58irqzwinl2k76oppjesmsp2mpfy72valgne","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/b\\/n\\/bnpp58irqzwinl2k76oppjesmsp2mpfy72valgne_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/b\\/n\\/bnpp58irqzwinl2k76oppjesmsp2mpfy72valgne_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":false,"userIsOnline":true,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=NqDMnwpbpqqmDgdyJQPZ&c=2edb9524fa70168fe93ae247c3833b80e0e7fda4","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"VWKqlByerzgqqjeNLYjZ","userName":"Erzwo93","userGender":1,"userAge":25,"userCity":"Weiterstadt","userPicId":"47kg45gyoqfs65gklaevshc2dmeieuaa7fclqt34","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/4\\/7\\/47kg45gyoqfs65gklaevshc2dmeieuaa7fclqt34_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/4\\/7\\/47kg45gyoqfs65gklaevshc2dmeieuaa7fclqt34_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":true,"userIsOnline":false,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=VWKqlByerzgqqjeNLYjZ&c=88acd872c5561d9c91427b4fbfc49bb7ff551e10","userLastVisited":""}],"count":199,"ts":"1559181753","settings":{"v":2}},"user":{"hasFavoritesOnline":false,"hasNewMessages":true,"hasNewNotifications":false,"hasNewHearts":false,"hasNewFeed":true,"hasProfilePic":false,"nickname":"sabhbau14","id_pic":"","gender":2,"id":"ogmJyDPalmEqPmbYEVRr","lastlogin":1559167342},"userSettings":{"bubbles":{"feed-visitors":0,"feed-visited":0,"feed-favorites":0,"info-gallery":0,"info-matching":0,"info-search":0,"info-mobile-likes":0,"info-mobile-search-custom":0,"info-mobile-search-newbies":0,"info-mobile-search-online":0,"info-mobile-favorites":0,"info-heart-sent":0,"deprecate-ie":1}},"context":"default","page":1,"pages_total":1,"userlist":[{"userId":"","userName":"vybz-kartel28","userGender":1,"userAge":26,"userCity":"Duisburg","userPicId":"wp24e3tn8m1rqlor90f3ithrwaqzsnoxv5zp6abj","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/w\\/p\\/wp24e3tn8m1rqlor90f3ithrwaqzsnoxv5zp6abj_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/w\\/p\\/wp24e3tn8m1rqlor90f3ithrwaqzsnoxv5zp6abj_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":false,"userIsOnline":true,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=knjlBZmdwrLzvVbMxLpW&c=48e7012db31d2944b912f83ff24af9dbee8fd7c3","userLastVisited":""},{"userId":"","userName":"Hanni89","userGender":1,"userAge":29,"userCity":"Laatzen","userPicId":"xiyx3e1bck1u033278wsp53xonxvhf5l9jy7n56q","userPictures":{"small":"\\/content\\/u\\/x\\/i\\/xiyx3e1bck1u033278wsp53xonxvhf5l9jy7n56q_12.jpg","medium":"\\/content\\/u\\/x\\/i\\/xiyx3e1bck1u033278wsp53xonxvhf5l9jy7n56q_3.jpg"},"userWasOnline":false,"userIsOnline":true,"userIsFavorite":false,"userIsNew":true,"userLinkToProfile":"\\/User\\/profile\\/?id=rmxkNywbnvvNVAbAXjpM&c=554a87e863f1b8f65a95a91575fed925e775dcca","userLastVisited":""},],"params":{"a1":"18","a2":"30","ct":"100006207","di":"200","g":"1","nm":"1","o":"1","pc":"1","ct_meta":{"id":"100006207","country":"de","city":"Paderborn","state":"Nordrhein-Westfalen","state_short":"NW","locality":"","id_zip_center":"7071","id_city_proxy":"100006207"}},"results_total":9,"max_per_page":30,"position":1,"getvars":{"ct":"100006207","g":"1","a1":"18","a2":"30","di":"200","ec":"","rx":"","sh":"","v1":"","hs":"","hc":"","h1":"","h2":"","ch":"","cp":"","ed":"","sm":"","zo":"","se":"","mo":"","o":"1","nm":"1","im":"","nn":""},"base_url":"\\/Search","nopage_url":"\\/Search\\/?ct=100006207&g=1&a1=18&a2=30&di=200&ec=&rx=&sh=&v1=&hs=&hc=&h1=&h2=&ch=&cp=&ed=&sm=&zo=&se=&mo=&o=1&nm=1&im=&nn=&","msg":"few_results","countries":{"de":"Deutschland","at":"\\u00d6sterreich","ch":"Schweiz","eg":"\\u00c4gypten","gq":"\\u00c4quartorialguinea","et":"\\u00c4thiopien","af":"Afghanistan","al":"Albanien","dz":"Algerien","ad":"Andorra","ao":"Angola","ag":"Antigua und Barbuda","ar":"Argentinien","am":"Armenien","az":"Aserbeidschan","au":"Australien","bs":"Bahamas","bh":"Bahrein","bd":"Bangladesch","bb":"Barbados","by":"Belarus","be":"Belgien","bz":"Belize","bj":"Benin","bt":"Bhutan","bo":"Bolivien","ba":"Bosnien und Herzegowina","bw":"Botsuana","br":"Brasilien","bn":"Brunei","bg":"Bulgarien","bf":"Burkina Faso","bi":"Burundi","cl":"Chile","cn":"China","cr":"Costa Rica","ci":"Cote d\'Ivoire","dk":"D\\u00e4nemark","dm":"Dominica","do":"Dominikanische Republik","dj":"Dschibuti","ec":"Ecuador","sv":"El Salvador","er":"Eritrea","ee":"Estland","fo":"Far\\u00f6er","fj":"Fidschi","fi":"Finnland","fr":"Frankreich","ga":"Gabun","gm":"Gambia","ge":"Georgien","gh":"Ghana","gi":"Gibraltar","gd":"Grenada","gr":"Griechenland","gb":"Gro\\u00dfbritannien","gt":"Guatemala","gn":"Guinea","gw":"Guinea-Bissau","gy":"Guyana","ht":"Haiti","hn":"Honduras","hk":"Hongkong","in":"Indien","id":"Indonesien","iq":"Irak","ir":"Iran","ie":"Irland","is":"Island","il":"Israel","it":"Italien","jm":"Jamaika","jp":"Japan","ye":"Jemen","jo":"Jordanien","kh":"Kambodscha","cm":"Kamerun","ca":"Kanada","cv":"Kap Verde","kz":"Kasachstan","qa":"Katar","ke":"Kenia","kg":"Kirgisistan","ki":"Kiribati","co":"Kolumbien","km":"Komoren","cg":"Kongo (Republik)","cd":"Kongo Dem. Republik","kp":"Korea (Nord) Dem. Volksrep.","kr":"Korea (S\\u00fcd) Republik","hr":"Kroatien","cu":"Kuba","kw":"Kuwait","la":"Laotische Dem. Volksrep.","ls":"Lesotho","lv":"Lettland","lb":"Libanon","lr":"Liberia","ly":"Libysch-Arabische Republik","li":"Liechtenstein","lt":"Litauen","lu":"Luxemburg","mo":"Macao","mg":"Madagaskar","mw":"Malawi","my":"Malaysia","mv":"Malediven","ml":"Mali","mt":"Malta","ma":"Marokko","mh":"Marshallinseln","mr":"Mauretanien","mu":"Mauritius","mk":"Mazedonien","mx":"Mexiko","fm":"Mikronesien","md":"Moldau","mc":"Monaco","mn":"Mongolei","me":"Montenegro","mz":"Mosambik","mm":"Myanmar","na":"Namibia","nr":"Nauru","np":"Nepal","nz":"Neuseeland","ni":"Nicaragua","nl":"Niederlande","ne":"Niger","ng":"Nigeria","nu":"Niue","mp":"N\\u00f6rdliche Marianen","no":"Norwegen","om":"Oman","pk":"Pakistan","pw":"Palau","ps":"Pal\\u00e4stina","pa":"Panama","pg":"Papua-Neuguinea","py":"Paraguay","pe":"Peru","ph":"Philippinen","pl":"Polen","pt":"Portugal","rw":"Ruanda","ro":"Rum\\u00e4nien","ru":"Russische F\\u00f6deration","sb":"Salomonen","zm":"Sambia","ws":"Samoa","sm":"San Marino","st":"Sao Tome und Principe","sa":"Saudi Arabien","se":"Schweden","sn":"Senegal","rs":"Serbien","sc":"Seychellen","sl":"Sierra Leone","zw":"Simbabwe","sg":"Singapur","sk":"Slowakische Republik","si":"Slowenien","so":"Somalia","es":"Spanien","lk":"Sri Lanka","kn":"St. Kitts und Nevis","lc":"St. Lucia","vc":"St. Vincent","sd":"Sudan","za":"S\\u00fcdafrika","sr":"Suriname","sz":"Swasiland","sy":"Syrien","tj":"Tadschikistan","tw":"Taiwan","tz":"Tansania","tl":"Timor-Leste","th":"Thailand","tg":"Togo","to":"Tonga","tt":"Trinidad und Tobago","td":"Tschad","cz":"Tschechische Republik","tr":"T\\u00fcrkei","tn":"Tunesien","tm":"Turkmenistan","tv":"Tuvalu","ug":"Uganda","ua":"Ukraine","hu":"Ungarn","uy":"Uruguay","us":"USA","uz":"Usbekistan","vu":"Vanuatu","va":"Vatikanstadt","ve":"Venezuela","ae":"Vereinigte Arab. Emirate","vn":"Vietnam","cf":"Zentralafrik. Republik"},"requestUri":"\\/Search?ct=100006207&g=1&a1=18&a2=30&di=200&ec=&rx=&sh=&v1=&hs=&hc=&h1=&h2=&ch=&cp=&ed=&sm=&zo=&se=&mo=&o=1&nm=1&im=&nn=","bubble_search":"\\n<div class=\\"tooltip tt-scheme1 tt-size2\\" id=\\"bubbleExpireNotice\\" style=\\"margin: 10px 0 20px;\\">\\n    <a href=\\"javascript:void(0);\\" class=\\"tt-close\\" data-closeaction=\\"\\/Ajax\\/hideBubble\\" data-closedata=\\"info-search\\" title=\\"Diesen Hinweis nicht mehr anzeigen\\"><\\/a>\\n    <div class=\\"tt-title tt-title-info\\">Sie suchen \\u2013 wir finden f\\u00fcr Sie<\\/div>\\n    <p>\\n        Wie stellen Sie sich Ihren Traumpartner vor? Wie alt, wie jung, wie gro\\u00df? Nutzen Sie die umfangreichen\\n        M\\u00f6glichkeiten der Partnersuche, und lassen Sie sich \\u00fcberraschen.\\n    <\\/p>\\n<\\/div>\\n"},

      };

(function() { var run = function()
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fsND5B/1/)